# Generate animation inside a container from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move a yellow square on the right side of the container, towards the left side of the container. The problem is that if it has no absolute position, it will not work.

Also I would like to know how to do the same animation with the second square, but that it starts to move one second after the first square. How can I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/ohtkmes8/

```js
var left = $('#coolDiv').offset().left;
$("#coolDiv").css({
  left: left
}).animate({
  "left": "0px"
}, 9000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
  <div id="coolDiv2">other text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To move an element to an arbitrary position within a container it *has* to be removed from the document flow, hence `position: absolute` is required. In most cases the container requires `position: relative` too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not works for me with position relative

Comment: Exactly my point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/q2kgmvog/

```js
$("#coolDiv").animate({"left":"0px"}, 9000);
```

```css
#coolDiv{
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
  <!--<div id="coolDiv2">other text</div>-->
</div>
```

Set the `position:absolute;` to the moving div & `right: 0px;`.

Animate it to `left:0px;` using `jQuery` animation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: where is the container??

Comment: @yavg.  Didn't get you, what do you mean by " 
where is the container??"

Comment: sorry! can you look my jsdfiddle? I forgot to put the link!

Comment: not man! no friend. I swear. I just forgot to attach the link That is why the question says that I must do this on a container.

Comment: @yavg. no worries.. Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/ohtkmes8/1/ . I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: you're very kind. But I need the animation inside the container. From the right of the container to the left of the container. I hope to make myself understood.